# Python-Sqlite : Write database error

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I try to write a network application. And stuck in how to write info to db (sqlite).

I collected systeminfo :

```
C:\Users\lnhqu>systeminfo

Host Name:                 DESKTOP-OIC0B0G
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Windows User
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                00330-50366-57669-AAOEM
Original Install Date:     02/12/2017, 12:22:29 SA
System Boot Time:          11/04/2018, 8:25:00 SA
System Manufacturer:       LENOVO
System Model:              20EQS1TQ00
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2712 Mhz
BIOS Version:              LENOVO N1EET62W (1.35 ), 10/11/2016
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
System Locale:             vi;Vietnamese
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta
```

And then i put it in a list like this :

```
['Host Name:                 DESKTOP-OIC0B0G\r', 'OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro\r', 'OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299\r', 'OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation\r', 'OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation\r', 'OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free\r', 'Registered Owner:          Windows User\r', 'Registered Organization:   \r', 'Product ID:                00330-50366-57669-AAOEM\r', 'Original Install Date:     02/12/2017, 12:22:29 SA\r', 'System Boot Time:          11/04/2018, 8:25:00 SA\r', 'System Manufacturer:       LENOVO\r', 'System Model:              20EQS1TQ00\r', 'System Type:               x64-based PC\r', 'Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.\r', '                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2712 Mhz\r', 'BIOS Version:              LENOVO N1EET62W (1.35 ), 10/11/2016\r', 'Windows Directory:         C:\\WINDOWS\r', 'System Directory:          C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\r', 'Boot Device:               \\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\r', 'System Locale:             vi;Vietnamese\r', 'Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)\r', 'Page File Location(s):     C:\\pagefile.sys\r', 'Domain:                    WORKGROUP\r']
```

I plan to write each element to an corresponding colum. But there is some issue with the Processor(s) row :

**Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.**

**[01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2712 Mhz**

The infomation not store in one line so when i put it in a list. It become two different element. If there is 2 Processor(s). It will become tree element in list. And i can't write to db correctly.

The db format look like this :
[DB Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsTSp.jpg).

There is only 1 colum to write processor infomation in db. So if there is 2 or 3 element for processor infomation in list. I can't write it to database.

Please give me some advices to solve this.